# Configuring web.xml in a Spring MVC with Hibernate project.DispatcherServlet and ContextLoaderListener have each a sessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, web.xml

Like the title says, am about to configure a Spring MVC project with Hibernate/JPA for persistence.

I remember I used the same context for both `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` until recently I've being advised to separate them. But in separating the I've found out that both were loading a `SessionFactory` making my `OpenSessionInViewFilter` a pain then I've separated the concerns, leaving only MVC concerns to the `DispatcherServlet`.

Aside having a mechanism to load collections when needed, when calling this parent objects, what are the other tips to avoid the infamous `LazyInitializationException`?

Answer (score 0):

If your "[unit of work](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow)" cannot be automatically per request, I think you can create it manually in your service layer using a transaction. Something like this:

```
public Object serviceMethod(params) {
   TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate; 
   transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
         public void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
         try {
        // call your DAO's to update/delete/... and set values to service
         } catch (DAOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
        throw new ServiceException(e);
         }
    }
});
}
```