# spring hibernate - share session beeween DAOs

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to use Spring + Hibernate in my web application. 
My application is written without Spring. 
When "open page" action is called I open Hibernate Session, store it in Http Session and share it between my DAOs. When save action is called I start transaction using my old session.

But now I want to migrate my old DAOs to HibernateDaoSupport based DAOs.
How can I share session in this case? If my DAOs reference to the one SessionFactory in beans.xml will they share the same session? 
How can I manage session in this case(open new or use old)?

I have write the following code but I get

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

on page System.out.println(obj.getCategory().getName());

```
public class CategoryObjectDAOSpringImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements CategoryObjectDAO {

@Override
public CategoryObject get(int id) throws Exception {


    CategoryObject obj = getHibernateTemplate().get(CategoryObject.class, id);

    System.out.println(obj.getId());


    System.out.println(obj.getCategory().getName());

    for (ObjAttrCommon objAttr : obj.getAttributes()) {
        //objAttr.setSession(getSession());
        System.out.println(objAttr.getId());
    }

    return obj;
}
```

It is strange that if I add

```
getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

call at the top I have the same exeption.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [same awswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313840/configuring-web-xml-in-a-spring-mvc-with-hibernate-project-dispatcherservlet-and/12316134#12316134) is valid for this post:

If your "[unit of work](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow)" cannot be automatically per request, I think you can create it manually in your service layer using a transaction. Something like this:

```
public Object serviceMethod(params) {
   TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = getHibernateTemplate().get(CategoryObject.class, id);
   transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
         public void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
         try {
        // call your DAO's to update/delete/... and set values to service
         } catch (DAOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
        throw new ServiceException(e);
         }
    }
});
}
```

**EDITED**: So extrange that the exception appears within a transaction. Make sure that the problem is not in your view. If after you retrieve your entites using HibernateTemplate you access it from the view it will explain the LazyException, because when you access your objects from the view, your Hibernate session will be already closed.

In you're using your models in your JSP/JSF your need to extend your unit of work to cover all request context. You have to include a filter that manages your Hibernate session opening, what is called Open Session In view Pattern, [take a look at this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView). 
Copy the filter implementation that appears in this post and include it in your application, it should solve the problem.

Comment: If I do like this I get LazyInitializationException. It seems that session and transaction are closed after it have worked.

Comment: The lazyinitializationException appears when you execute your Hibernate queries in the service layer/DAO layer or whan you access your object in your view (JSP/JSF)?

Comment: I've edited my reponse explaing how to solve the open in view session problem.

Comment: Thanks kothvandir, Open Session In view Pattern have helped me.